# Theme unexpectedly changed to Gnome

Tags: release-loki, gnome, desktop-environment

I am not sure what I did in order to end up with the Gnome theme, but the beautiful elementary OS desktop is gone and now I'm seeing the Gnome theme.

I have tried purging `elementary-desktop`, reinstalling it and rebooting, but it did not help.

See screenshots below:

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the elementary-theme isn't deleted, but it just changed it somehow?

Try opening terminal and execute:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme elementary
```

This will set elementary as your theme again. If you don't want to use the command line you could install Gnome-tweak-tool or elementary tweak for changing.

Comment: I just used elementary tweaks and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that!